# chess grid not hiding second span

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid

some help required.
i have multiple div like a chess grid. upon rollover single gird its inner span scroll up inside the grid and bottom hidden span appear. following is the code which is not working in that manner.

```
    <section id="three">
    <div class="tri"><h1>Corporate</h1></div>
    <div class="corporate">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#">
                <span style="background:#06F">1</span><!--
                --><span style="background:#0CF">2</span>
            </a><!--
            --><a href="#"><span style="background:#06F">1</span><span style="background:#0CF">2</span></a><!--
            --><a href="#"><span style="background:#06F">1</span><span style="background:#0CF">2</span></a><!--
            --><a href="#"><span style="background:#06F">1</span><span style="background:#0CF">2</span></a>
        </div><!--
        --><div class="right">
            <a href="#">1</a><!--
            --><a href="#">2</a><!--
            --><a href="#">3</a><!--
            --><a href="#">4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

keeping in mind i am using percentage in order to show it to different devices. following is the css for grid

```
#three{display:block;}
#three .corporate{display:table; height:70%; width:98%; margin:0 auto;}
#three .corporate div{display:table-cell; width:50%; margin-left:0;}

#three .corporate div a{height:50%; background:#F90; display:inline-table; width:50%; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:#FFF; overflow:hidden; position:relative}
#three .corporate div a span{display:table-row; width:100%; height:100%}
#three .corporate div a:hover > span{bottom:0}
```

please help.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of OP's code http://jsfiddle.net/XnQpB/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are wanting to do, but it sounds like the span tags that hold "2" should be hidden and only appear when the "1" is hovered over.

Adding a new class "hidden-span" to control the span tags that should be hidden makes this a bit easier.

```
#three .corporate div a span.hidden-span 
{ 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: -100%; 
  z-index: 2; 
}
```

Also, the original span style needs to be altered a bit.

```
#three .corporate div a span
{
  display:table-row; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  z-index:1; 
  transition: bottom .5s; 
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zTEd/)

Comment: [http://vrhiring.com/suzuki/lane12/](http://vrhiring.com/suzuki/lane12/) please find corporate section. i am improving it with percent width and percent height.

Comment: upon rollover first anchor margin top in -ve and next anchor show it self. just like that